# Mongo GridFS support for Vert.x 3.2.0

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, vert.x, gridfs

I am trying to store the binary content in Mongo DB GridFS.

I want to know if there is Mongo DB GridFS support in Vert.x 3.2.0
I do not see any official note about this recently. 
Please provide me the guide

Also I was planning to use either Vert.x or Spring boot (which has spring data supporting for GridFSOperations already) for my microservice - wondering which one I should prefer from long term perspective as far as GridFS support is concerned ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think they have support for MongoDB's GridFS, but you can always "ask for it" by creating an issue in the [Vert.x Mongo Client](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-mongo-client) repository (hosted on GitHub).

In the end, they might create a new repository or put that functionality in that one itself.

On the other hand, Spring already [have support](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/1.10.6.RELEASE/reference/html/#gridfs) for GridFS, so if you are in a hurry, I think it's a better fit for you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [Spring Content](https://paulcwarren.github.io/spring-content/) for your solution?

It is designed to work on its own or with Spring Data.

There are a couple of getting started guides [here](https://paulcwarren.github.io/spring-content/).  They use Spring Content Filesystem but the modules are interchangeable.  The Mongo reference guide is [here](https://paulcwarren.github.io/spring-content/refs/release/mongo-index.html).  And there is a tutorial video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pbDaONWWT3s) showing how easy it is to write a "content service" with these technologies.  As I said all interchangeable with the Spring Content Mongo (GridFS) module.

HTH

Comment: I am using mongodb driver async v 3.4.1 for this purpose and creating a connection for gridfs  bucket to get instance of GridFSBucket. With GridFSBucket we can query Mongo GridFs

Comment: I know I was a little late to the party with my answer.  Sounds like you already got something implemented.  But just in case.  The advantage of Spring Content is that you wouldn't need to concern yourself with writing the actual implementation for storing/retrieving binary content.  Spring Content would provide this for you based on an interface you provide.  Also Spring Content (and Data) provide an abstraction that would allow you to move your implementation to other repostories/stores very easily too; i.e. it protects against vendor lock-in.  HTH